# This `do..while` loop isn't working

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

```
int sc1,sc2,a=0,b=0;

do
{

 printf("Give the scores\n");

 scanf("%d %d", &sc1,&sc2);

 //===============================================

 if (sc1 > sc2)     
   a+=1;
 else if (sc1<sc2)
   b+=1;
 else if (sc1==sc2)
   printf("tie\n");

 //===============================================

 if (a>b)    
    printf("team 1 is in the lead\n");
 else if (a<b)
    printf("team 2 is in the lead\n");
 else if (b==a)
    printf("tie\n");      

}
while((a==3) || (b==3));

//===============================================


if (a==3)
  printf("team 1 got the cup");
else
  printf("team 2 got the cup");
```

I think that I wrote something wrong. I've searched it a lot but can't seem to find what is wrong with it.

(One of the two teams can win the cup and that team has to have 3 wins)

*else if(sc1

*else if(a>b)

Comment: It would help if you describe exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: why not use cin and cout instead of scanf and printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question properly you'd like the terminating condition to be that one of the teams "a" or "b" has a score of 3.  However, in your code you've written that the only way the while can loop is if one of the teams has a score of 3.  You want:

```
while( !( a==3 || b == 3) )
```

Comment: @Seth Carnegie `not` is a gcc extension, `!` is proper.  Good catch.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't use g++ so I'd never heart of `not`. Sorry about that.

Comment: `not` is an alias for `!`, not an extension.

Answer (score 3):

```
while((a==3) || (b==3));
```

will loop only if `a` or `b` is three. If you want to wait until one of them is three, use:

```
while ((a!=3) && (b!=3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop condition is incorrect.  It is stopping early because neither team has a score of 3.  Loop until one or the other gets up to 3:

```
while((a < 3) && (b < 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're telling it to loop while a or b still equal 3. Which is not what you want. You want `while((a<3) && (b<3))`

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional:

```
while((a==3) || (b==3));
```

States that the loop will continue so long as either `a` or `b` are equal to 3. Are you sure this is what you wanted?

Comment: yes I want to enter scores until one of the two teams (team1 or team20 reaches 3 (wins).

Comment: @Nikos Angelis Junior - I suggest you check your code. What happens if team1 wins 4 times?

Comment: It can't reach 4, the do..while will terminate (increment is fixed to 1).